# How can I override the max heap size (Xmx) for junit tests in Intellij? (setting in the Edit Configuration dialog just prepends it)

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to set the max heap size for a junit test in intellij, and the value that I enter into the VM Options field is merely prepended. Without attempting to override Xmx, the run command shown by `ps aux` is the following:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -ea -javaagent:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.8/jmockit-1.8.jar -Xmx1024m -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 ...
```

If I add the custom Xmx config, it shows up, but the later value of 1024m is still appended to the run command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -ea -Xmx4G -javaagent:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.8/jmockit-1.8.jar -Xmx1024m -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 ...
```

How do I correctly set or override Xmx here? I searched in `~/idea-IC-172.3317.76/bin/idea.properties` and in `~/.IdeaIC2017.2/config/` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml files, Maven options defined for the tests override IDEA defaults, it's by design.